# How to get SharePoint Online List data from Outlook VSTO Addon

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, sharepoint-online

I've developed a VSTO add-on for Outlook that my company uses which connects to a SQL database to read/write data. I'd like to change the data source to SharePoint Online since all employees have M365 accounts. This will also allow the add-on to operate outside of the corporate network.

If I setup a SharePoint online site with a few lists, is there a way to have the Outlook VSTO Add-on read/write from the lists?

Also, since the Outlook client is already authenticated, is there a way to bypass any sort of authentication and use the already authenticated Outlook client when talking to SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to consider your add-in as a standalone .Net based application. You can use the SharePoint client object model (CSOM) to retrieve, update, and manage data in SharePoint. Read more about that in the [Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) article.